# Model + Controller inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys i have 2 controllers . Generator and Result. In order to get the Result i need the Generator's value ( somehow the value has been stored in the model).

May i know how should i get the data from the generator so that i can have the value of Generator and do what i must for the Result ?

```
#result_controller.rb 
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_result, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :generate_result, only: [:create]
  # GET /results
  # GET /results.json
  def index
    @results = Result.all
  end

  # GET /results/1
  # GET /results/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /results/new
  def new
    @result = Result.new
  end

  # GET /results/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /results
  # POST /results.json
  def create
    @result = Result.new(result_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @result }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /results/1
  # PATCH/PUT /results/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.update(result_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /results/1
  # DELETE /results/1.json
  def destroy
    @result.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to results_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def set_ncbi_ref_seq
    @result.ncbi_ref_seq = params[:ncbi_ref_seq]
    generate_result
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_result
      @result = Result.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def result_params
      params.require(:result).permit(:ncbi_ref_seq)
    end
end
```

In my generatorController

```
#generator_controller.rb
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :generate_option, only: [:create, :update]
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def generate_option
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
    if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
        random_generate
    elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'
        no_ATGC
    elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
        seating
    end
   @generator.save!
  end

  private
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length, :choice, :random_primer_generated)
    end
end
```

in ApplicationController

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception 

  def random_generate
     length = @generator.primer_length
     length=length.to_i
        chars = 'ATGC'
        seq = ''
        length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
       @generator.random_primer_generated = seq

       @generator.c_primer =Bio::Sequence::NA.new(@generator.random_primer_generated.reverse)
       @generator.c_primer=@generator.c_primer.complement.upcase
  end

  def no_ATGC 
    counts = {'A'=>params[:no_A],'T'=>params[:no_T],'G'=>params[:no_G],'C'=>params[:no_C]}
   # total=params[:no_A]+params[:no_T]+params[:no_G]+params[:no_C]
    @generator.random_primer_generated = Bio::Sequence::NA.randomize(counts).upcase
    @generator.primer_length = @generator.random_primer_generated.length

    @generator.c_primer =Bio::Sequence::NA.new(@generator.random_primer_generated.reverse)
    @generator.c_primer=@generator.c_primer.complement.upcase
  end

  def seating()       
    desired_random_primer=params[:user_seq]
    @generator.primer_length = desired_random_primer.length
    user_seq_xspace= params[:user_seq].delete('*') 
    empty_slots=@generator.primer_length-user_seq_xspace.length() 
    length = empty_slots
        chars = 'ATGC'
        seq = ''
        length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
    temp_random_primer_generated = seq

    no=0 
    n=0
    while n < @generator.primer_length do
     if desired_random_primer[n] == "*" 
       desired_random_primer[n]=desired_random_primer[n].replace(temp_random_primer_generated[no])
       no+=1
     else
       desired_random_primer[n]=desired_random_primer[n]
     end
     n+=1
    end
    @generator.random_primer_generated = desired_random_primer 

    @generator.c_primer =Bio::Sequence::NA.new(@generator.random_primer_generated.reverse)
    @generator.c_primer=@generator.c_primer.complement.upcase
  end

  *def generate_result
    ref_seq = @result.ncbi_ref_seq
    Bio::NCBI.default_email = "haha@hotmail.com"
    fasta_sequence = Bio::NCBI::REST::EFetch.nucleotide(ref_seq,"fasta")
    fasta=Bio::FastaFormat.new(fasta_sequence)
    @result.genome_seq = fasta.data
    @result.genome_sample = fasta.definition

    p=@generator.genome_seq.scan(@generator.c_primer)
    @result.binding_times = p.length()

    @result.save
  end*

end
```

Comment: Where is the inheritance? Are `Generator` and `Result` models? Attach some code to clarify your question, otherwise no one will be able to understand a tiny bit from your question!

Comment: Yes they're 2 different models.         p=@generator.genome_seq.scan(@generator.c_primer)
@result.binding_times = p.length()

Comment: So, again, you have 2 models or 2 controllers? Where's the inheritance? Please edit your question and add some piece of code (not a function call). How's your routing set up? etc.

Comment: How should i do declare the inheritance if i'm using Aptana as my IDE . I mean where should i code them in . It's really confusing. I'm putting all my methods to generate all those attribute values in ApplicationController instead of ModelController. I tried putting them in Models but i can't pass params to my model that is why i switch back to Controller.

Comment: You don't "declare" inheritance. Have you ever heard of OOP? Like a class inheriting from another? `class ChildClass < ParentClass` *inheritance*.
Also, rails does not depend on Aptana or whatever IDE you are using. Everything you need is in the code. Edit your question and ATTACH your code. All your models and controllers. Between triple backticks so they are displayed as code.

Comment: ? 2 models = 2 controllers right ? Sorry new to rails ... There isn't any inheritance yet. But i would like to know if i need them to do the above code. How can i get another model's value for my current controller to process the work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33204/discussion-between-rewritten-and-bc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your controllers.

1. methods in ApplicationController are for things like shared loading or utility methods (typical candidate: `current_user` (memoized) which will be available to all controllers. Methods which belong to a specific controller don't go into the AppController.
2. If you want a Generator instance in the ResultsController, you need a way to retrieve it. From params or from a foreign key on the Result instance.
3. Don't use `after_action` to modify your models, everything could happen, the model may not have been saved, and the app flow is very obscure.

I'd rather put some intelligence in the model, for instance

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base

  # other stuff you already have

  def set_primer_from_counts(num_a, num_t, num_g, num_c)
    counts = {'A'=>num_a,'T'=>num_t,'G'=>num_g,'C'=>num_c}
    random_primer_generated = Bio::Sequence::NA.randomize(counts).upcase
    primer_length = random_primer_generated.length
    c_primer = Bio::Sequence::NA.new(random_primer_generated.reverse)
    @generator.c_primer = c_primer.complement.upcase
  end

end


class GeneratorController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)
    @generator.set_primer_from_counts(params[:no_A], params[:no_T], params[:no_G], params[:no_C])
    # ....
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm clear with number 1. But for number 2, could you give me some guideline how to retrieve the Generator instance using a foreign key ? ( i understand that it's throught generator.id) but where should i place the code in

Comment: The right question is: "how do you expect the user (or the system) to choose a generator?". Maybe it is a user choice in a form, maybe it depends on some property of the created Result record... anyway you need to decide, and then implement.